# How to use tf.reset_default_graph()

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Whenever I try to use `tf.reset_default_graph()`, I get this error: `IndexError: list index out of range` or ``. At which part of my code should I use this? When should I be using this?

Edit:

I updated the code, but the error still occurs.

```py
def evaluate():
    with tf.name_scope("loss"):
        global x # x is a tf.placeholder()
        xentropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=neural_network(x))
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")

    with tf.name_scope("train"):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    with tf.name_scope("exec"):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            for i in range(1, 2):
                sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
                sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={x: np.array(train_data).reshape([-1, 1]), y: label})
                print "Training " + str(i)
                saver = tf.train.Saver()
                saver.save(sess, "saved_models/testing")
                print "Model Saved."


def predict():
    with tf.name_scope("predict"):
        tf.reset_default_graph()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("saved_models/testing.meta")
            saver.restore(sess, "saved_models/testing")
            output_ = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('output_layer:0')
            print sess.run(output_, feed_dict={x: np.array([12003]).reshape([-1, 1])})


def main():
    print "Starting Program..."
    evaluate()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("mygraph/logs", tf.get_default_graph())
    predict()
```

If I remove the tf.reset_default_graph() from the updated code, I get this error:  `ValueError: cannot add op with name hidden_layer1/kernel/Adam as that name is already used`

From my current understanding, tf.reset_default_graph() removes all graphs, hence I avoided the error I mention above(`ValueError: cannot add op with name hidden_layer1/kernel/Adam as that name is already used`)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is probably how you use it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.reset_default_graph()
```

You get an error because you use it in a session. From the `tf.reset_default_graph()` documentation:

> Calling this function while a tf.Session or tf.InteractiveSession is
>   active will result in undefined behavior. Using any previously created
>   tf.Operation or tf.Tensor objects after calling this function will
>   result in undefined behavior

---

`tf.reset_default_graph()` can be helpful (at least for me) during the testing phase while I experiment in jupyter notebook. However, I have never used it in production and do not see how it would be helpful there.

Here is an example that could be in a notebook:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# create some graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run(...)
```

Now I do not need this stuff anymore, but if I create another graph and visualize it in tensorboard I will see old nodes and the new nodes. To solve this, I could restart the kernel and run only the next cell. However, I can just do:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
# create a new graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(...)
```

**Edit after OP added his code**:

```
with tf.name_scope("predict"):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Here is what approximately happens. Your code fails because `tf.name_scope` already added something to a graph. While being inside of this "adding something to the graph", you tell  TF to remove the graph completely, but it can't because it is busy adding something.

Comment: So basically `tf.reset_default_graph()` is only used in testing but not used for applications running all day?

Comment: @CodingNoobie I never used it for any other reason apart of testing and experimenting. It does not mean that it can't be used, I just never saw a point of using it.

Comment: I tried placing it outside of a running session, but I still experience the same error. I have updated the post with some code. Hope it helps.

Comment: @CodingNoobie put reset graph before `with tf.name_scope("predict"):`

Comment: Nice! The error message is gone. Why is that? Why does shifting it outside  solve the problem?

Comment: @CodingNoobie added explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148276/discussion-between-coding-noobie-and-salvador-dali).

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, I need to build a new graph FOR LOTS OF TIMES, and I have just tested, which works eventually! Many thanks for Salvador Dali's answer:-)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from my_models import Classifier

for i in range(10):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    # build the graph
    global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)
    classifier = Classifier(global_step)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        print("do sth here.")
```

Answer (score 3):

With TensorFlow 2.0 coming out, now it's better to use `tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()` in order to avoid getting warning.  Link to the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/reset_default_graph

Answer (score -2):

simply put,
use to clear previous placeholder which you using sess.run() created

Comment: Kindly use Comments section and if you can't, post proper Answers please!